# Java sequential chaining hashing

Tags: java, hash, chaining, sequential

Just looking for some help/insight into what this question is asking..maybe someone could even point me in the right direction for eventually solving it.

I currently have a complete separate chaining hash table algorithm using the standard hashing function:

```
(key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % M
```

*Anyways, the question...............*

Insert the keys `E A S Y Q U T I O N` in that order into an initially empty table of `M = 5` lists, using separate chaining. Use the hash function `11 K % M` to transform the Kth letter of the alphabet into a table index.

I am by no means a hashing expert, but after working on this topic for a few weeks this question still appears to me as being complete gibberish.

EDIT
if it helps, here is the hashtable code:

```
public class SeparateChainingHashST<Key, Value> {
private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 4;


private int N;                                // number of key-value pairs
private int M;                                // hash table size
private SequentialSearchST<Key, Value>[] st;  // array of linked-list symbol tables


// create separate chaining hash table
public SeparateChainingHashST() {
    this(INIT_CAPACITY);
}

// create separate chaining hash table with M lists
public SeparateChainingHashST(int M) {
    this.M = M;
    st = (SequentialSearchST<Key, Value>[]) new SequentialSearchST[M];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        st[i] = new SequentialSearchST<Key, Value>();
} 

// resize the hash table to have the given number of chains b rehashing all of the keys
private void resize(int chains) {
    SeparateChainingHashST<Key, Value> temp = new SeparateChainingHashST<Key, Value>(chains);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (Key key : st[i].keys()) {
            temp.put(key, st[i].get(key));
        }
    }
    this.M  = temp.M;
    this.N  = temp.N;
    this.st = temp.st;
}

// hash value between 0 and M-1
private int hash(Key key) {
    return (key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % M;
} 

// return number of key-value pairs in symbol table
public int size() {
    return N;
} 

// is the symbol table empty?
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

// is the key in the symbol table?
public boolean contains(Key key) {
    return get(key) != null;
} 

// return value associated with key, null if no such key
public Value get(Key key) {
    int i = hash(key);
    return st[i].get(key);
} 

// insert key-value pair into the table
public void put(Key key, Value val) {
    if (val == null) { delete(key); return; }

    // double table size if average length of list >= 10
    if (N >= 10*M) resize(2*M);

    int i = hash(key);
    if (!st[i].contains(key)) N++;
    st[i].put(key, val);
} 

// delete key (and associated value) if key is in the table
public void delete(Key key) {
    int i = hash(key);
    if (st[i].contains(key)) N--;
    st[i].delete(key);

    // halve table size if average length of list <= 2
    if (M > INIT_CAPACITY && N <= 2*M) resize(M/2);
} 

// return keys in symbol table as an Iterable
public Iterable<Key> keys() {
    Queue<Key> queue = new Queue<Key>();
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (Key key : st[i].keys())
            queue.enqueue(key);
    }
    return queue;
} 


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    SeparateChainingHashST<String, Integer> st = new SeparateChainingHashST<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; !StdIn.isEmpty(); i++) {
        String key = StdIn.readString();
        st.put(key, i);
    }

    // print keys
    for (String s : st.keys()) 
        StdOut.println(s + " " + st.get(s)); 

}
```

}

Comment: It's not really a question, it's a directive. What is your question, and what sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @hatchet it is a directive, I supposed following that directive is the "question" and successfully doing so is the "answer". I am just unsure as to how I can follow it, and exactly what it is asking me to do

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret the problem, I don't think you want to be calling the hashcode method. The problem mentions the 'Kth letter of the alphabet'. Using that, I would assume that 'E' is the 4th letter of the alphabet (with 'A' being the 0th). Applying the hash function they give, that would be `(11 * 4) % 5 = 4`. So, 'E' is added as the first entry to the list at M[4]. You would then repeat this for the other letters.

The problem is not clear on whether the 'Kth letter' is zero based or one based; i.e. is 'A' the zeroeth letter or the first letter? I'm assuming it's the zeroeth, calculated by `KeyLetter - 'A'`. I'm also assuming that `11 K % M` means `(11 * K) % M`.

Comment: ok thanks. that helps a lot, hadn't thought about it in that way.
on that note however is there a quick or even built-in method in java for finding the alphabetic number of a letter?

Comment: @user3245237 - you can can just subtract, as in `int k = 'E' - 'A';`. Of course, if you have to worry about uppercase/lowercase, non-ASCII characters, etc. that can complicate it. But if you're just talking A-Z, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. First, let's look at the formula:

> (K * 13) % M

Where:

`K = position of the letter in the alphabet (starting from 1).`

`13 = constant`

`M = fixed size of our array (in this case we are going to imagine is 6, starts from 0).`

```
E    (5 * 13) % 6 = 5
A    (1 * 13) % 6 = 1
S    (19 * 13) % 6 = 1
Y    (25 * 13) % 6 = 1
Q    (17 * 13) % 6 = 5
U    (21 * 13) % 6 = 3
E    (5 * 13) % 6 = 5
S    (19 * 13) % 6 = 1
T    (20 * 13) % 6 = 2
I    (9 * 13) % 6 = 3
O    (15 * 13) % 6 = 3
N    (14 * 13) % 6 = 2
```

If we wanted to visualize these results in an array with a fixed length of 6 (remember, we start counting here from 0), we would end with "S N O E." If the numeric value gets repeated as result of the formula, then exchange.

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
               E         
   A           E
   S           E
   Y           E
   Y           Q
   Y     U     Q
   Y     U     E
   S     U     E
   S  T  U     E
   S  T  I     E
   S  T  O     E
   S  N  O     E
```